# Differences between alpha, beta, development and patched releases (e.g. of R)?

Tags: r, release, software-distribution

I think my questions are about various releases of any software, although taking R as an example.

From http://cran.r-project.org/sources.html,

> **R Sources**
>
> **Official releases**
>
> Official releases of R source code are most likely what you want if
> you are looking for the sources of R (both Unix and Windows). ...
>
> The latest release (2014-10-31, Pumpkin Helmet): R-3.1.2.tar.gz
>
> - Changes to the previous version are documented in the file NEWS (also contained in the sources).
> - Older releases are available here.
>
> **Snapshots**
>
> Snapshots of R sources for development and patched release versions
> can be obtained as gzipped and bzipped tar files from
> ftp://ftp.stat.math.ethz.ch/Software/R/:
>
> - **Sources of R alpha and beta releases** (daily snapshots, created only in time periods before a planned release).
> - **The latest patched release**: R-patched.tar.gz, R-patched.tar.bz2 (read what's new in the latest patched version).
> - **The latest development release**: R-devel.tar.gz, R-devel.tar.bz2 (read what's new in the latest devel version).
>
> After downloading the R sources you should also download the
> recommended packages by entering the R source tree and running
>
> ```
> tools/rsync-recommended
> ```
>
> from a shell command line.
>
> The above archives are created automatically from the Subversion tree,
> hence might not even compile on your platform and can contain any
> number of bugs. They will probably work, but maybe not. Use them to
> verify whether a bug you're tracking has been fixed or a new feature
> you always wanted has already been implemented.
>
> CRAN itself does no longer mirror source snapshots (as of 2001-11-14),
> because it makes only limited sense to propagate archives that change
> on a daily basis through a network of mirror sites. When a snapshot
> reaches one of the final nodes in the mirroring process, there are
> already 2 newer versions available at the orginal sites.

My questions are:

- Is it correct that the latest "Official releases" is the source distribution for the latest binary release, without any pack since the time for the latest binary release?
- What are the differences  between alpha, beta, development and patched releases  of R?
- How are they related to the latest official release?
- what differences are between "alpha/beta releases" and "the latest development release"?
- Does "the latest patched release" only apply to the latest stable release not to a development release?

Thanks!

Comment: Also relevant: the ["Software Development Life Cycle" document](http://www.r-project.org/doc/R-SDLC.pdf)

Comment: Thanks. I searched in the file. Still not clear about: (1) what differences are between "alpha/beta releases" and "the latest development release"? (2) Does "the latest patched release" only apply to the latest stable release not to a development release?

Answer (score 0):

Release numbers are groups of digits separated by dots:

Example:
software Foo 2.3
software Bar 5.11.4

In addition to the numeric components, projects sometimes tack on a descriptive label such as **"Alpha" or "Beta"**, for example:

Foo 2.3.0 (Alpha)
Bar 5.11.4 (Beta)

An Alpha or Beta qualifier means that this release precedes a future release that will have the same number without the qualifier. Thus, "2.3.0 (Alpha)" leads eventually to "2.3.0".

The three labels, "Alpha", "Beta", and "RC" (for "Release Candidate"), are pretty widely known now.

In a typical three-component system, the first component is the major number, the second is the minor number, and the third is the micro number (also called the "patch" number). For example, release "2.10.17" is the eighteenth micro release (or **patch release**) in the eleventh minor release line within the second major release series.

Some projects,  add a fourth component, usually called the patch number, for especially fine-grained control over the differences between their releases (confusingly, other projects use "patch" as a synonym for "micro" in a three-component system, as shown before). I think R work with four-digit system but do not show the last number in the website, naming the versions generically as “patched versions”. consider. I.e., the patched version means the “hidden” fourth numbers of the release 3.4.1, for instance.

*Excerpts of the book Producing Open Source Software: How to Run a Successful Free Software Project, by Karl Fogel.*
http://producingoss.com/